# Covariant derivative on Christoffel symbols

Tags: riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations

I'm looking for an explanation for the meaning of the terms on the right side of the following:

\begin{eqnarray}\frac{d}{dt} \Big( \bar{R}_{ij} \Big)\Big|_{t=0} =  \dot{\Gamma}^k_{ij;k} - \dot{\Gamma}^{k}_{ki;j},\end{eqnarray}
where 
$$\dot{\Gamma}^k_{ij} = \frac{d}{dt}\Big( \bar{\Gamma}^{k}_{ij} \Big)\Big|_{t=0} = \frac{1}{2}g^{kl}(h_{il;j} + h_{jl;i} - h_{ij;l})$$
and the bar denotes the dependence on $\bar{g} = g + th$, for a metric $g$, a symmetric $(0,2)$-tensor $h$, and $t \in (\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ (so we have a one-parameter family of metrics on a fixed manifold $M$).

EDIT: $\dot{\Gamma}$ is a tensor.  Thus it makes sense to take the covariant derivative.  That is,

\begin{align*}
\dot{\Gamma}^k_{ij;\ell} = (D_{\partial_{\ell}}\dot{\Gamma})(dx^k,\partial_i,\partial_j) &= \dot{\Gamma}^k_{ij,\ell} - \dot{\Gamma}(D_{\partial_{\ell}}dx^k, \partial_i, \partial_j) - \dot{\Gamma}(dx^k,D_{\partial_{\ell}}\partial_i, \partial_j) - \dot{\Gamma}(dx^k,\partial_i, D_{\partial_{\ell}}\partial_j)\\
&= \dot{\Gamma}^k_{ij,l} -\dot{\Gamma}([\partial_{\ell}(dx^k(\partial_n)) - dx^k(D_{\partial_{\ell}}\partial_n)]dx^n, \partial_i,\partial_j) -\Gamma^n_{\ell i}\dot{\Gamma}^k_{nj} - \Gamma^n_{\ell j}\dot{\Gamma}^k_{in}\\
&= \dot{\Gamma}^k_{ij,l} +\Gamma^k_{\ell n}\dot{\Gamma}^n_{ij} -\Gamma^n_{\ell i}\dot{\Gamma}^k_{nj} - \Gamma^n_{\ell j}\dot{\Gamma}^k_{in}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I'm confused---you are looking at a one-parameter family of metrics $\bar g(t) = g + th$? How is $\bar g$ related to $\bar R$? The curvature tensor is additional structure not fully determined by the metric (it depends on the embedding, whereas the metric does not)...

Comment: $\bar{R}_{ij}$ is the $ij$-th component of the Ricci tensor with respect to the metric $\bar{g}$. I am taking this from http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.599.8478&rep=rep1&type=pdf (page 4 of the pdf)

Comment: If I recall correctly, even though $\Gamma$ is not a tensor, that difference of $\Gamma$s is.

Comment: ...which implies that the time derivative of $\Gamma$ is a tensor, so these terms do indeed make sense.